# Getting xmpp messages while app is in background in android

Tags: android, xmpp

As the app disconnects it stops getting messages from xmpp server. For background notification purpose, I am using GCM service. Now, Just like WhatsApp I want my app too to receive the messages in background and save them in sqlite.

```
Is it necessary for this task that my app would always be connected to
xmpp server?
Will it not load the xmpp server Since, so many sessions the server 
will have to keep alive?
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't set keep alive for less then 10 minutes this will load the server.

When app is in the background then you have to send push notification via gcm for android and apns for iPhone. For this to implement you need to implement plugin on openfire.

Comment: I am already receiving push notifications from my ejabberd server. I just want to know that : (1.) Should I keep the device 24x7 login on ejabbrd server. Or (2.) use the push notification as the indication that a new message has come And then login the device internally for some minutes to receive the message in background and then disconnect silently.

Comment: Another problem is that, Is it must to take PARTIAL_WAKELOCK in order to receive the messages from server. I have tested that Other apps like(WhatsApp) doesnt use PARTIAL_WAKELOCK for this. Even then, their messages are saved in background without taking PARTIAL_WAKELOCK. Currently Stuck in big problem. I would be highly thankful to you:-)

Comment: Don't login user 24x7. When app is in the background then show push and insert message in the database, actually I am getting full message in push .

Comment: But As the GCM Push messages are not sure that they all will definitely be received on device. Hence, There may be a loss of messages if not delivered by GCM.

Comment: I have never seen messages lost in gcm. One of my other aap is totally based on gcm. If message is lost then its implementation problem

Comment: When the app is in sleep state and as the GCM Message received. Is it sure that the app will be in awake state until app finishes its message handling task without taking any WAKELOCK?

Comment: i'm doing FCM integration with Ejabbered and i also receiving push but how to stop pingManager which is ping on some interval because of it XMPP is send message when app is background rather than FCM @JaspreetChhabra